# SQL - Setting a Default Value from Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm currently working on writing a trigger for my database, with table `employee` and column `dno`. Before writing the trigger, I specified `dno` to have a default value of `1`, and in the trigger I want to enforce the default value if the value in `dno` is to be deleted.

This is what I have so far. It seems pretty straightforward to me, but I feel like I'm missing a lot.

```
create trigger empdeptfk_delete
on employee
after delete as
begin
update employee
set dno = 1
end
```

Is there a way I can write `set default value` instead of `set dno = 1`? Also, I'm using SQL Server 2012, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: You should handle the update trigger ( not the delete ) of the employee table if you want to catch only 'dno' field's value changes.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: If are going to delete one record from employee table then the field is already gone!! You mentioned that if the value of the column is deleted, you want it to have the value of 1, so you have to handle the update trigger of the employee table to set the dno field value to 1, I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the Update trigger instead of the delete trigger, because you need to catch when dno field is being UPDATED.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER empdeptfk_update ON employee
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(dno)
            BEGIN

                DECLARE @DNO INT
                SELECT  @DNO = dno
                FROM    Inserted

                IF @DNO IS NULL
                    SET @DNO = 1

                UPDATE  employee
                SET     employee.dno = @DNO
                FROM    Inserted
                WHERE   Inserted.employeeID = employee.employeeID

            END
    END
```

Comment: I tried the above code, and then afterwards attempted to update some tuple in `employee`, but was successful in setting `dno` to null. I have `update employee set dno = null where lname = 'smith'` where lname is the last name of some person in the employee table.

Answer (score 0):

First create 'trigger before delete' then do the update dno=1 and then do the delete.

Comment: actually before=instead of